# How can I create an outlook rule to stop my outgoing email if I haven't selected the right From address for the associated recipient?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, rules

If a corporation has multiple support email addresses, depending on the customer, you want to ensure that you respond from the correct address. There is only one email account within the company.

How can I create an outlook rule to stop my outgoing email if I haven't selected the right From address for the associated recipient?

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is no such rule settings in Outlook client. If your mail system is Exchange server, try the [Exchange Transport rule](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd351127(v=exchg.150).aspx). It can block the emails before the specified messages arrive to the recipients' mailbox, and give the sender an Non-Delivery Report to why the email was not delivered successfully.

Besides, it would be better if you can share more details about the right from address for the associated recipients, so we can try to give more specific suggestions :)